# How to upload react+nodeJS/express to heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm having a problem uploading my project to heroku,
I have a main folder which contains Server folder and client folder,
they are all updated on git and I made the server scripts for the build just as in brad traversy's guide, but as soon as I try to do heroku push, 
I get this message : "No default language could be detected for this app."
I tried then to upload it in the Server folder, same thing,
I tried to set BuildPack to nodejs, no success either, am I missing something?

Comment: Please give more information - what is Brad Traversy's guide, [this](https://www.udemy.com/nodejs-express-mongodb-dev-to-deployment/)? Assuming people don't want to pay £150 to help you out, could you summarise what you've actually done in the question? It seems like Heroku can't guess what buildpack you want to use, have you tried specifying that somewhere, or giving it something like a `package.json` it can infer it from?

Comment: I used the MERN stack on his youtube channel, the only difference is that he had his server and client in the same folder, I have them on two different folders, the package.json is present in the Server folder, but how do I specify that?

Comment: See e.g. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs